# android facebook login and publish button

Tags: android

I am trying to make an application which can have only one button to login and post facebook feed using feed dialog, I have read the tutorial from facebook for login in and feed dialog which is https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/login-with-facebook/ and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/feed-dialog/. But in these two tutorials, they are using two button to do the login and publish feed action. Here is the code that what I am doing right now and it gives me error.

This is my main class:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class Main extends FragmentActivity {
private MainFragment mainFragment;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // Add the fragment on initial activity setup
        mainFragment = new MainFragment(this, Main.this);
        getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .add(android.R.id.content, mainFragment)
        .commit();
    } else {
        // Or set the fragment from restored state info
        mainFragment = (MainFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
        .findFragmentById(android.R.id.content);
    }
}
```

This my Fragment class:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookOperationCanceledException;
import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.SessionState;
import com.facebook.UiLifecycleHelper;
import com.facebook.widget.WebDialog;
import com.facebook.widget.WebDialog.OnCompleteListener;

public class MainFragment extends Fragment{
private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
private Button shuffle, fbshare;
@Override

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);
    fbshare = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.share);      


    fbshare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            publishFeedDialog();
        }
    });
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
 // For scenarios where the main activity is launched and user
    // session is not null, the session state change notification
    // may not be triggered. Trigger it if it's open/closed.
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null &&
           (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed()) ) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
    }
    uiHelper.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    uiHelper.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    uiHelper.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
    }
};

private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    if (state.isOpened()) {
        fbshare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    } else if (state.isClosed()) {

    }
}

private void publishFeedDialog() {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session == null){
        session = new Session(getActivity());
        Session.setActiveSession(session);
    }
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("name", "Facebook SDK for Android");
    params.putString("caption", "Build great social apps and get more installs.");
    params.putString("description", "The Facebook SDK for Android makes it easier and faster to develop Facebook integrated Android apps.");
    params.putString("link", "https://developers.facebook.com/android");
    params.putString("picture", "https://raw.github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.x-howtos/master/Images/iossdk_logo.png");

    WebDialog feedDialog = (new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(getActivity(),Session.getActiveSession(),params)).setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values, FacebookException error) {
            if (error == null) {
                // When the story is posted, echo the success
                // and the post Id.
                final String postId = values.getString("post_id");
                if (postId != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Posted story, id: "+postId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    // User clicked the Cancel button
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Publish cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } else if (error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException) {
                // User clicked the "x" button
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Publish cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                // Generic, ex: network error
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Error posting story", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }).build();
    feedDialog.show();
}
}
```

my errors from logcat:

```
03-07 21:05:52.527: E/AndroidRuntime(2052): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-07 21:05:52.527: E/AndroidRuntime(2052): com.facebook.FacebookException: Attempted to use a Session that was not open.
03-07 21:05:52.527: E/AndroidRuntime(2052):     at com.facebook.widget.WebDialog$BuilderBase.<init>(WebDialog.java:392)
03-07 21:05:52.527: E/AndroidRuntime(2052):     at com.facebook.widget.WebDialog$FeedDialogBuilder.<init>(WebDialog.java:553)
03-07 21:05:52.527: E/AndroidRuntime(2052):     at com.example.projectapp.MainFragment.publishFeedDialog(MainFragment.java:306)
03-07 21:05:52.527: E/AndroidRuntime(2052):     at com.example.projectapp.MainFragment.access$11(MainFragment.java:293)
3-07 21:05:52.527: E/AndroidRuntime(2052):  at com.example.projectapp.MainFragment$3.onClick(MainFragment.java:221)
03-07 21:05:52.527: E/AndroidRuntime(2052):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
03-07 21:05:52.527: E/AndroidRuntime(2052):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
03-07 21:05:52.527: E/AndroidRuntime(2052):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
03-07 21:05:52.527: E/AndroidRuntime(2052):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-07 21:05:52.527: E/AndroidRuntime(2052):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-07 21:05:52.527: E/AndroidRuntime(2052):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
03-07 21:05:52.527: E/AndroidRuntime(2052):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-07 21:05:52.527: E/AndroidRuntime(2052):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-07 21:05:52.527: E/AndroidRuntime(2052):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
03-07 21:05:52.527: E/AndroidRuntime(2052):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-07 21:05:52.527: E/AndroidRuntime(2052):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can someone tell me why is this error happen and what can I do to fix the error and make the button work?

I am using the latest facebook sdk, it is really confusing for me, is there any other tutoriala that I can try to letorn the facebook sdk?

This is my first time I use this site, if I am doing anything wrong please let me know and I will try to do it right.

Thanks.